# Calculate Array of Discounts

Tags: javascript, percentage

How can I calculate the Array of Discounts against Base Price in initial then calculate against the Amount After Discount?

In the screenshot below, I have the Base Price. This base price can have multiple discounts.

[image]

Each discount can be given only after the calculated Base Price.

My PHP script here is the below;

```php
<tbody>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class=\"col-sm-3\" style='color: green'><strong>Base Price</strong></label>
        <div class='col-sm-8'>
            <input type='number' class='form-control' id='basePrice' name="basePrice" value='5985'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    $query = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `manage_customers_discount` WHERE status = 1 AND company_id = '1' AND discount_is_deleted = 0");
    $query->execute();
    $query->store_result();

    $rows = $query->num_rows;
    $rows = $rows + 1;

    $arrayDiscountNumber = 0;
    for ($y = 1; $y < $rows; $y++) { ?>

        <tr id="row<?php echo $y; ?>" class="<?php echo $arrayDiscountNumber; ?>">
            <td style="margin-left:20px;">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <select class="form-control" name="discountName[]" id="discountName<?php echo $y; ?>" onchange="getDiscountData(<?php echo $y; ?>)">
                        <option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>
                        <?php
                            $discountSql = "SELECT * FROM `manage_customers_discount` WHERE status = 1 AND company_id = '1' AND discount_is_deleted = 0 ORDER BY discount_order ASC";
                            $discountData = $connect->query($discountSql);

                            while ($row = $discountData->fetch_array()) {
                                echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' id='changeDiscount" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['discount_name'] . "</option>";
                            } // /while

                            ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                <input type="text" name="rateDiscount[]" id="rateDiscount<?php echo $y; ?>" autocomplete="off" disabled="true" class="form-control" />
                <input type="hidden" name="rateDiscountValue[]" id="rateDiscountValue<?php echo $y; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                <input type="text" name="totalDiscount[]" id="totalDiscount<?php echo $y; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" disabled="true" />
                <input type="hidden" name="totalDiscountValue[]" id="totalDiscountValue<?php echo $y; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                <input type="text" name="amountAfterDiscount[]" id="amountAfterDiscount<?php echo $y; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" disabled="true" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amountAfterDiscountValue[]" id="amountAfterDiscountValue<?php echo $y; ?>" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>

                <button class="btn btn-default removeDiscountRowBtn" type="button" id="removeDiscountRowBtn" onclick="removeDiscountRow(<?php echo $y; ?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        $arrayDiscountNumber++;
    } // /for
    ?>
</tbody>
```

As you can see in the screenshot, I have calculated the base price which has given me the first Amount after Discount `Base Price * 15%`. In the second discount, I need to calculate the `First Amount After Discount * 10%`. Same with the 3rd discount. The last Amount after Discount will display in the Sub Discount Amount.

Below is my JS,

```js
var subTotalValue = $('#basePrice').val();

$("#rateDiscount" + row).val(response.percentage);
$("#rateDiscountValue" + row).val(response.percentage);

var total = Number(response.percentage) * Number(subTotalValue);
total = total.toFixed(2);
$("#totalDiscount" + row).val(total);
$("#totalDiscountValue" + row).val(total);

var total = Number(subTotalValue) - Number(total);
total = total.toFixed(2);
$("#amountAfterDiscount" + row).val(total);
$("#amountAfterDiscountValue" + row).val(total);
```

PROBLEM: It is calculating all the percentage against the Base Price

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it's an ugly one. I just want to share with you this because I know you can translate this code to a better one. I'm not an expert programmer, so please do not laugh or vote down my solution. I just want to share this with you not to tell that this is correct. Again, this is to give you an idea.

Now,

Since I have this on my `SELECT` option `onchange="getDiscountData(<?php echo $y; ?>)"`,
I just manually check the row. That if the `row == 1` then it should take the base price. 
Else, it will take the first `Amount After Discount`.

See the ugly code below.

```
                        if(row == 1){
                            var subTotalValue = $("#basePrice").val();

                            $("#rateDiscount"+row).val(response.percentage);

                            var total = Number(response.percentage) * Number(subTotalValue);
                            total = total.toFixed(2);
                            $("#totalDiscount"+row).val(total);

                            var total = Number(subTotalValue) - Number(total);
                            total = total.toFixed(2);
                            $("#amountAfterDiscount"+row).val(total);
                        }
                        if(row == 2){
                            var subTotalValue = $("#amountAfterDiscount"+1).val();

                            $("#rateDiscount"+row).val(response.percentage);

                            var total = Number(response.percentage) * Number(subTotalValue);
                            total = total.toFixed(2);
                            $("#totalDiscount"+row).val(total);

                            var total = Number(subTotalValue) - Number(total);
                            total = total.toFixed(2);
                            $("#amountAfterDiscount"+row).val(total);
                        }if(row==3){
                            var subTotalValue = $("#amountAfterDiscount"+2).val();

                            $("#rateDiscount"+row).val(response.percentage);

                            var total = Number(response.percentage) * Number(subTotalValue);
                            total = total.toFixed(2);
                            $("#totalDiscount"+row).val(total);

                            var total = Number(subTotalValue) - Number(total);
                            total = total.toFixed(2);
                            $("#amountAfterDiscount"+row).val(total);
                            $("#subDiscountAmount"+row).val(total);
                        }
```

In case you may require the same solution, just make it the best as you can.